# Vertx multiple servers in one verticles

Tags: vert.x

I noticed that we can use Vert.x to write multiple Verticles and communicate using EventBus. Is this way different from writing some servers in just one Verticle?

Comment: No, You can create multiple vert.x instances as different microservices. A whole vertx app runs as a single application and thus have a dedicated port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create different servers in the same verticle, but all user requests will be handled by the same event loop.

This might work just fine for you use case. However usually it's best for clarity/performance to separate concerns.